# Android custom view draw BitmapDrawable render on preview section incorrectly

Tags: android, android-custom-view

There are two views on this example. Left one is my custom view and the right one is ImageView. ImageView seem to draw correctly on preview screen. However, both view draw correctly on running device.

But I want it to show correct preview like ImageView does. What did I do wrong ?

**PREVIEW**

[image]

**RUNNING DEVICE**

[image]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.apg.mobile.repeatlayout.MainActivity">

    <com.my.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/aa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:src="@drawable/samplebg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/aa"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/samplebg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomView**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        readAttribute(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        readAttribute(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        readAttribute(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void readAttribute(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);
        Drawable drawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomView_src);

        if (drawable == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("You have to set src first..");

        bitmapDrawable = drawableToBitmapDrawable(drawable);

        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int wm, hm;
        int viewHeightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int viewWidthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

        Log.d("VIEW WIDTH-MODE", getMode(viewWidthMode));
        Log.d("VIEW HEIGHT-MODE", getMode(viewHeightMode));

        // 1: find user desired dimension
        int desiredWidth = measureDesiredSize(widthMeasureSpec, bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth());
        int desiredHeight = measureDesiredSize(heightMeasureSpec, bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        wm = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth, viewWidthMode);
        hm = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredHeight, viewHeightMode);
        setMeasuredDimension(wm, hm);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        bitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        bitmapDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    private int measureDesiredSize(int measureSpec, int imageSize) {

        int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int size = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            return size;
        } else if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            return Math.min(size, imageSize);
        } else {
            return imageSize;
        }
    }

    public BitmapDrawable drawableToBitmapDrawable(Drawable drawable) {

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {

            return (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        } else if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {

            // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        } else {

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        }
    }


    private String getMode(int mode) {

        if (MeasureSpec.AT_MOST == mode) {
            return "AT_MOST";
        } else if (MeasureSpec.EXACTLY == mode) {
            return "EXACTLY";
        } else {
            return "UNSPECIFIED";
        }
    }
}
```

**Attribute**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="src" format="reference" />    
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**Resource**

[Sample drawable](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuuk7u5mag1p697/dot.png?dl=0) please put it in drawable folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solved my problem by using width and height form onSizeChanged.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        mViewWidth = xNew;
        mViewHeight = yNew;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        bitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, mViewWidth, mViewHeight);
        bitmapDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
```